# Bug in app in login activity of firebase auth

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to develop a blood donation app

But when I started to run it it crashed and showed in Logcat that there was a bug in my loginactivity.java

I had been stuck at

```
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

my studio shows me an error as in
logcat:

> com.android.iunoob.bloodbank.activities.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:38)

As for that I tried the solutions like:   FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);  but it's not the cup of tea for this problem.

```
package com.android.iunoob.bloodbank.activities;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.iunoob.bloodbank.R;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button signin, signup, resetpass;
    private EditText inputemail, inputpassword;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pd.setMessage("Loading...");
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Dashboard.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }

        inputemail = findViewById(R.id.input_username);
        inputpassword = findViewById(R.id.input_password);

        signin = findViewById(R.id.button_login);
        signup = findViewById(R.id.button_register);
        resetpass = findViewById(R.id.button_forgot_password);

        signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String email = inputemail.getText().toString().trim();
                final String password = inputpassword.getText().toString().trim();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email) || TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please fill in all fields.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    pd.show();
                    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                    pd.dismiss();
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Dashboard.class);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        finish();
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        Log.e("LoginError", "Authentication Failed: " + task.getException().getMessage());
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }
            }
        });

        signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        resetpass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RestorePassword.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the crash log?

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question. Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: When an app crashes, it writes an error message and stack trace to its logcat. Please find those, and add them to your question by clicking the `edit` link under it. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors